# Did not get any event when dragging file on Outlook specific folder

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I have created one add-in for outlook 2013. There is one "custom folder 1" on outlook.

When I drag one file on desktop and drop it in "custom folder 1" folder, I did not get any event.

Comment: Fischermaen
i want to add watcher on my outlook folder. so when user try to drag file on my folder i will upload that file on drive. thats y i want a notification event when file added in my folder.

Comment: Where in outlook "customer folder 1" created? Is it create inside a live account? Or is it inside Outlook Data File? What does that folder contain?

Comment: @sameerkn i have attached one screen short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Items.ItemAdd` event will fire when a new item (such as an item created by dropping a file) is created.